# My Windows 10 (File) Explorer closes when right clicking on a file

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Please help, this is annoying and I have no idea where to start looking

In Windows 10, if open a File Explorer window (Win-E) and then go to a directory. If there's a file which an extension not associated to any program and I right click, I got what is supposed to do: a contextual menu which starts with **Open with...**, some other extensions work as well, like **.zip** (I have no zip manager, I use the one provided with ths OS)

If the file is associated with an extension, like a **.xlsx**, **.pdf**, **.jpg** and so on, and I right click, it shows the waiting circle, and then the File Explorer closes.

I believe some program installed a handler or something like that. I have been uninstalling everything I recently installed, that might be causing the problem, among other things,

- Autohotkey
- Microsoft Visual Code
- 7Zip file manager
- WinRAR
- Notepad++
- FoxIt PDF

I really, really don't want to uninstall MS Office, but I don't know what else to look for

I'm currently running a **`sfc /scannow`** to see if I got some files corrupted, but I really don't know what else to do.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had this issue since February 2017. I have an ASUS computer. I uninstalled Foxit Phantom PDF and the right click works again everywhere. Maybe you will have the same luck?

Comment: Yes, in the end, it was the Foxit Phantom PDF. Mi PC is also an ASUS, it came preinstalled with the PC. I'm writting an answer on how I diagnosed this, thank you very much

Comment: Had exactly the same issue. Unbelivable. Now,who is to blame, Asus or Foxit?

Answer (score 3):

As Celeste says, the problem was caused by **Foxit Phantom PDF** that came preinstalled with my ASUS PC.

Here's how I diagnosed the error. The captures are in spanish, but I'm pretty sure you'll understand what's going on:

- After my File Explorer crashed that last time, I went to the Event Manager and looked for an error
- I found this error on the File Explorer, and the description pointed in the Foxit direction:

[image: Screen capture]

So I uninstalled the program and everythng is working as it should. Strange thing is I rarely use this program, so I don't think it was updated, and the problem just recently showed up.